# debugモジュールで標準出力に表示されないのはなぜ？（`process.env.DEBUG`で環境変数を設定しているつもりなんだけど）

Tags: javascript, node.js

### 質問

以下のjsファイルをnodeコマンドで実行しても、標準出力に"start"と表示されませんでした。
なぜでしょうか？

```
const debug = require('debug')('puppeteer-loadtest');
process.env.DEBUG = "puppeteer-loadtest";
debug('start');
```

上記ファイルを実行する前に、コマンドで環境変数を設定`set DEBUG=puppeteer-loadtest`した場合、標準出力に`puppeteer-loadtest start +0ms`と表示されました。
`process.env.DEBUG = "puppeteer-loadtest";`で環境変数は設定されていると考えているので、なぜ標準出力に"start"が表示されないのかが疑問です。

### 環境

- node v10.13.0

### 補足

以下のモジュールを使ったときに、標準出力にデバッグ情報が出力が出なかったので、ここで質問しました。
https://github.com/svenkatreddy/puppeteer-loadtest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

確かに`process.env.DEBUG = "puppeteer-loadtest";`で環境変数DEBUGを設定できるのですが、その例ではDEBUGを設定するのが遅すぎます。

というのも、`DEBUG`の値が読み込まれるのはdebugオブジェクトを作ったとき、すなわち`const debug = require('debug')('puppeteer-loadtest');`が実行されたときだからです。（[ソースコードでいうとここです。](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/7ef8b417a86941372074f749019b9f439a1f6ef6/src/common.js#L259)）

ですから、それよりも更に前に`process.env.DEBUG`を設定することでちゃんと"start"と表示されます。

```
process.env.DEBUG = "puppeteer-loadtest";
const debug = require('debug')('puppeteer-loadtest');
debug('start');
```

とはいえ、常に`process.env.DEBUG`を一番最初に設定するのは現実的ではないかと思います。あとからデバッグログを有効化するには、`process.env.DEBUG`を使うのではなく別の方法があります。

以下のように[`enable`メソッド](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug#set-dynamically)を用いることであとからデバッグログを有効化できます。下の例を試すと"start"と表示されるかと思います。（`enable`メソッドを利用するために`require('debug')`の結果を別の変数`createDebug`に入れています。）

```
const createDebug = require('debug');
const debug = createDebug('puppeteer-loadtest');
createDebug.enable('pupeteer-loadtest');
debug('start');
```

Comment: >一番最初に設定するのは現実的ではないかと思います。一番最初に設定するのは現実的ではないかと思います。
具体的にどういった部分が現実的でないのでしょうか？
また、`enable`メソッドを使った場合のメリットが分かりませんでした。
コードの順番に左右されるのが良くない、ということですか？

Comment: @yuji38kwmt やりたいことによっては「後から設定を変更したい」という場合もあり、そのような場合はDEBUG環境変数を設定する方法は使えませんので、そのような場合には使えない方法であるという意味で「現実的ではない」と書きました。　一番最初に設定できれば十分であるという場合は、DEBUG環境変数を設定する方法でも問題ないと思います。　　`enable`メソッドを使う場合のメリットですが、メリットというよりは、「あとから設定したい」という場合には`enable`メソッドを使うのが唯一の方法になるかと思います。　　`DEBUG`でも大丈夫な場合でも、 `require`よりもさらに上にコードを書くのは分かりにくいので、自分の好きな場所で呼べるというのはメリットと言えるかもしれません。